# Passing array to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am a newbie in xcode. I am trying to pass an array from one view to another. I want to pass an integer `profileid` in the ProfileViewController to an array in the FavouritesViewController.
Once the FavouritesViewController is loaded the log will display the array.

Here's my code:

**ProfileViewController.h**

```
- (IBAction)AddFavouritesClicked:(id)sender;
```

**ProfileViewController.m**

```
@synthesize profileid;


int profileid = 0;

- (IBAction)AddFavouritesClicked:(id)sender {

    FavouritesViewController *favController = [[FavouritesViewController alloc]init];
    [favController.favouritesArray initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:profileid], nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", favController.favouritesArray);


}
```

**FavouritesViewController.h**

```
@interface FavouritesViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *favouritesArray;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *favouritesArray;
@end
```

**FavouritesViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"%@", favouritesArray);
}
```

So far the `favouritesArray` value is always `null`

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is my Log every time I clicked the `Addtofavoutites` button

```
2013-01-27 22:54:52.865 Ad&Promo[8058:c07] (
2
)
2013-01-27 22:56:10.958 Ad&Promo[8058:c07] (
2
)
2013-01-27 22:56:11.705 Ad&Promo[8058:c07] (
2
)
2013-01-27 22:56:12.191 Ad&Promo[8058:c07] (
2
)
```

But instead I want it to look like this..

```
2013-01-27 22:54:52.865 Ad&Promo[8058:c07] (
2,2,2,2
)
```

Comment: Unrelated to xcode, and the code wasn't indented properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should review the syntax for your array creation. It should be:

```
favController.favouritesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:profileid], nil];
```

This alone will not fix your issues, though, I gues

This is quite a typical error that shows up here on S.O. In the following 2 statements:

```
FavouritesViewController *favController = [[FavouritesViewController alloc]init];
favController.favouritesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:profileid], nil];
```

you are allocating a new `FavouritesViewController`. That has nothing to do with any other `FavouritesViewController` that you have already initialized in your app. That explain why its internal array is empty.

What you need to do is make your `ProfileViewController` instance aware of your FavouritesViewController instance (as opposed to instantiating a private instance of the latter inside the former).

So, simply define a `FavouritesViewController` property inside of `ProfileViewController`, and initialize it properly. Then you will be able to do:

```
- (IBAction)AddFavouritesClicked:(id)sender {

    self.favController.favouritesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:profileid], nil];
```

}

and this will set the value you need to set into the other view controller you have.

EDIT:

a better design for this kind of requirement is using a *model* (as in model-view-controller).

Instead of letting one of the two controllers know about the other, you create a new class (the model) responsible for holding all the shared data in your app.

This class would be accessible from any other class in your app, so that they could set and get the data it stores.

This class could be a singleton:

```
[MyModel sharedModel].favArray = ...
```

or it could be a class exposing only class methods, e.g.:

```
[MyModel setFavArray:...];
```

Comment: About initWithObjects: "An array initialized to include the objects in the argument list. The returned object might be different than the original receiver."

Comment: that's right, thanks. anyway, I don't think that fixing the syntax for the array initialization will solve the issue. the issue, as far as I understand, is that the first controller knows nothing about the second one, so it's setting the array content for the wrong object (a local, private one).

Comment: How can I save the values in the array? When I clicked on the action the array is passed on but the value isn't saved in the array. I have edited. I have edited the question to show you what I mean. Thanks again!

Comment: what mechanism do you use to display the second view? what does the button do?

Comment: @sergio the button only passes the array to the `FavouritesViewController`. The FavouritesViewController is a TableViewController that is connected to the TabbarController

Comment: please, show the code where you assign `favController` to `profileViewController.favController`. also, check my edit for an alternative design you could apply.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning the pointer and you're missing the alloc method, do it this way:

```
favController.favouritesArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:profileid], nil];
```

Comment: How can I save the values in the array? When I clicked on the action the array is passed on but the value isn't saved in the array. I have edited. I have edited the question to show you what I mean. Thanks again!